# How to use the same variable for both plugin and dependency version in Gradle build script?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I have a Gradle plugin and a dependency that are on the same release cadence and use the same version number. Thus, I want to define a single variable that would hold a version number to be used by both a plugin and a version:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.6.0'
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "$kotlinVersion"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.0"
}
```

The `kotlinVersion` variable defined inside the `buildscript` code block can be used only for plugins and not for dependencies.

Is it possible to use the same variable for both a plugin and a dependency?

Comment: I tried this `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion"` and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, @samabcde. That works. I tried the same some time ago and for some reason, it didn't work. I guess I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may reuse the definition of a variable that is set with `gradle.properties`, but it needs to be separated to two files: first the `settings.gradle.kts` that defines the plugins you use in your project and the usage, in the place of your `build.gradle.kts`.

Based on the: https://docs.gradle.org/5.6/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management

Define a version in `gradle.properties`:

```
helloPluginVersion=1.0.0
```

And use it when defining a plugin with a version, in `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
val helloPluginVersion: String by settings
pluginManagement {
  plugins {
    id("org.gradle.sample.hello") version "${helloPluginVersion}"
  }
}
```

Later on, you may just use the plugin in a `build.gradle.kts` without specifying the version (it was already defined in `settings.gradle.kts`), and as well reuse that version in your dependencies block:

so:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.gradle.sample.hello")
}
val helloPluginVersion: String by project
dependencies {
 implementation("org.gradle.sample.hello:plugin:$helloPluginVersion")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should not use a variable like that and also not how Augustin suggested.

Instead you should use a version catalog as documented at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html, preferable in TOML format. With a version catalog, you can easily use the same version for dependencies and plugins.

---

In your specific case it actually is not necessary at all.
Applying the Kotlin Gradle plugin automatically adds the Kotlin BOM to the project dependencies. This BOM contains the version for `kotlin-reflect`. So you can just depend on `kotlin-reflect` without any version and it will just work.

Nevertheless I recommend using a version catalog for defining libraries, plugins, and versions as it also has other advantages.

---

And one personal additional recommendation: You should switch to Kotlin DSL for the build scripts. By now it is the default DSL, you immediately get tpye-safe build scripts, actually helpful error messages if you mess up the syntax, and an amazingly better IDE support if you use a good IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio.